# TabBar disappearing after launching UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift

In my project, or if you refer to the attached storyboard, I have a UITabBarController embedded in UINavigationController with rootview as UIViewController. Look at the GIF I've attached, notice how my Tab bar disappears when I click into "Choose From My Images" and it disappears after "Cancel".

My codes are as follows:

Inside my "Choose From My Images" button

```
@IBAction func chooseLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    picker.allowsEditing = true

    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Inside my "Cancel" button

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I've also attached my storyboard just in case.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have not provided enough information here, is that a real UITabBar and controller? if so, there are settings to hide on push, but it looks more like you are just putting the view on another view? I can't see the related code so I can't tell but you should check the hidesWhenPushed or similar settings to be sure those are as you'd expect.

Comment: Yes, I drag out a UITabBarController, and have a UINavigationController embedded in it. Lastly, a UIViewController as a root view. Could you elaborate how hideWhenPushed can help?