# UITabBar disappears upon modal dismiss of UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

After much research, I think I found the problem to my application, but I cannot find the solution to it.

In my project, as shown in the screenshot, I have a `UITabBarController` as the initial viewcontroller. `UINavigationController` will "show (push)" to display `UIViewController`. Inside my `UIViewController`, I will call `UIImagePickerController` which is set by XCode to present on "Modal".

The issue comes in, when I dismiss the `UIImagePickerController`, the UITabBar items disappears. I know it has got to do with dismissing the modal, but I can't find solution to it.

[image]

My codes as follow:

On click of a button inside `UIViewController`

```
@IBAction func chooseLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    picker.allowsEditing = true

    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

On click of "Cancel" inside `UIImagePickerController`

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Why do not use self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil) ?

Comment: Do the items disappear or the tab bar itself disappears?

Comment: this is the second time I posted this question, and based other comments, they said to use `self.navigationController?.presentViewController`. However, either ways do not work.

Comment: Hi @beyowulf, refer to this link which I previously posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927381/tabbar-disappearing-after-launching-uiimagepickercontroller/34927812#34927812

Comment: Can you post all of the code in chooseLibrary? Seems like you've left stuff out because at the very least you're setting the barTintColor of picker.navigationBar

Comment: errr...this is all the codes i have in chooseLibrary.

Comment: @beyowulf, by the way, my BarTintColor was set inside my AppDelegate

Comment: I'm not sure why it's hiding then, but you should add         self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
to imagePickerControllerDidCancel

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func chooseLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    picker.allowsEditing = true

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(picker, animated: true)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: `UIImagePickerController` is a modal present. While `popViewControllerAnimated` is for push. I've also tried, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Set **viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO**; for all the controllers in which you want to show your tab bar.
This flag must be set when you push / present your view controller.
Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, hidesBottomBarWhenPushed is used for Show or Push, not for modal. As UIImagePickerController is a modal, hidesBottomBarWhenPushed would not work.

Comment: @jo3birdtalk Yep, "hidesBottomBarWhenPushed" doesn't work with modal. Do you know how to hide the "bottomBar" when a modal is presented  ?